# Rate limit using Redis?

Tags: redis

There's an API used by multiple users, is it possible to implement rate limit using Redis?

Would be interesting to know how to do it for two slightly different cases:

- No more than X requests per second from same user.
- No more than X concurrent requests from same user.

The API implemented as stateless ruby processes running on multiple servers.

Comment: I think the question could be better answered if you specify how to distinguish between different requests from the same user in your context.

Comment: It doesn't matter if requests are the same or not, each request treated as unique. We can generate random number for each request and use it as the ID.

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [rack-attack](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) gem. It can use Redis for store information about requests for throttling.

Comment: The Rack layer is a good spot for this, very light-weight compared to having it deep in a controller.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's not Ruby, but I've implemented a rate limiter using [ioredis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis) and the Redis commands are easily transferable. Ioredis is a wrapper for Node.js but the redis calls are the same.

[Here's a gist of rolling window and lockout-style rate limiters](https://gist.github.com/ChisholmKyle/b44fa64d5252eee59041)

For the second part of your question, I'm not sure what you mean by concurrent requests? Aren't requests transient and sequential by definition? Do you mean concurrent connections? The number of devices a user has connected at one time, for example? You would only need to keep track of the number connections in that case (no need for a timer).